# How to change mapping type on a very large ElasticSearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, type-conversion, elastic-stack

I tried to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71968055/12320885) from here, but it didn't worked for me.

I needed to convert the nested text fields like ***one.second.third*** to ip type. So I added mapping like

```
PUT .the-index-2022.12.20-0000025/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "one": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "second": {
          "type":"object",
          "properties": {
            "ip_address1": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "ip_address2": {
              "type": "ip"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I used

```
POST .the-index-2022.12.20-0000025/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false&slices=auto
```

It executed successfully but still didnt change the fields type to ip.

What can I do else or what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Also tried like:

```
PUT .the-index-2022.12.20-0000025/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "one": {
      "properties": {
        "second": {
          "properties": {
            "ip_address1": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "ip_address2": {
              "type": "ip"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please help?

I've added 3 new fields in ip type:

```
{
  ".the-index-2022.12.20-0000025" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "one.sec.ip1" : {
        "full_name" : "one.sec.ip1",
        "mapping" : {
          "ip1" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          }
        }
      },
      "one.sec.ip2" : {
        "full_name" : "one.sec.ip2",
        "mapping" : {
          "ip2" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          }
        }
      },
      "one.sec.ip3" : {
        "full_name" : "one.sec.ip3",
        "mapping" : {
          "ip3" : {
            "type" : "ip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [My solution you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71968055/12320885) has probably not been applied like it's supposed to. You need to create a sub-field (of type `ip`) of your `text` field, but **not try to replace** your text field, it's not going to work. You cannot change a field type from `text` to `ip` (or to any other type for that matter), you can only 1) fake it by creating a sub-field of the desired type; or 2) reindex your data into a new index with the right mapping type

Comment: I've added 3 new fields in type ip. From pipeline new values parsed targeting these fields. I see the values of the fields but still in text type even though i use "_update_by_query". Should I do smt else? what am i missing? See in the post newly created fields.

Comment: I don't see where `one.second.third` are in your examples. Also what "pipeline" are you referring to? Can you share it?

Comment: Just added. Coming logs have a field which contains 3 ips like `field: 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3`. I am parsing them and targeting new 3 fields which I've created. Then i use the convert processor, but still text type. What am i trying to do in the end is 
`ip1: 1.1.1.1`,`ip2: 2.2.2.2`,`ip3: 3.3.3.3`
I'm getting the fields with the values but not as ip type. Coulnd't change it.

Comment: Can you show what you get from `GET .the-index-2022.12.20-0000025/_mapping` please? (i.e. the real mapping, not the one you think you've set)

Comment: The last part in the question is the result of `GET .the-index-2022.12.20-0000025/_mapping/field/one.sec.ip1,one.sec.ip2,one.sec.ip2`

Comment: Ok, and where do you see that your new IP fields are still of type text?

Comment: in logs, table view. But I checked later again, now it says conflicting field. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe provide screenshots, because it's not clear what "table view" you're referring to

Comment: see the post, `t` is text field I mentioned, the red ones are conflicting field. It seems like that

Comment: The conflicting field issue is a different issue than this one, that warrants another question so as not to mix too many different things together.

Comment: Please show the data view definition for your index and how the new IP fields look like in that data view

Comment: You mean as json?

Comment: Your mapping is obviously, right, I'd like to see what Kibana sees in your data view (formerly index pattern)